# Is everything made of space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, theory-of-everything

I had been studying quantum field theory for a while now, and how there had been many efforts in physics to finally create a "Theory of Everything" (TOE).  But while I was learning about all this, I began to wonder:  Is everything (matter and energy) just the result of quantum "ripples" in the vacuum of space?  Discoveries such as virtual particles and the Casimir effect made me wonder if the vacuum of space really is the only material thing in the entire universe (or multiverse), and that matter and energy is just the result of fluctuations in space, also considering the fact that quantum field theory described particles as excitations in an underlying physical field (not to mention the fact that we can actually see the material presence of the vacuum in phenomena such as Einstein rings).  Is this true, and could it really lead to a true Theory of Everything (it being an alternative to the abstract idea of string theory)?

Comment: voting to close, unpublished personal theory

Comment: You wonder a lot!

Comment: "unpublished personal theory"... The idea that everything is just made of space is part of physics history (e.g. the study of "geons"), and you could argue that supergravity as a theory of everything was just a slight generalization of this idea - geometry plus supersymmetry.